# Makefiles and metadata drawn from entire codebase: Accelerating build using diff between old/new

Tags: bash, build, makefile, build-process

I have a build system with a preprocessor that uses static information from the whole codebase.

```
       [metadata]
            |
[input] -(preprocess)-> [source] -(compile)-> [executable]
```

Important notes:

1. Both `(preprocess)` and `(compile)` can take a considerable amount of time per source file.
2. [metadata] usually changes everytime you edit *any* sourcefile in the repository.

So, obviously something needs to be done to cut down on recompiles. So I thought to be clever and did a script that basically works like this:

```
create [source_temp] using [input] and [metadata]
does [source] not exist yet or is [source_temp] different? --> move [source_temp] to [source]
```

This works in that recompiles only happen when there is an actual change in [source].

**However**

In the case when [source] == [source_temp], [source] stays older than [metadata]. So next time I'm running make, even though [metadata] hasn't changed from before, all the (preprocess) commands are repeated since [metadata] is newer.

So... what's the most elegant way to

1. have GNU Make not run (preprocess) if both [metadata] and [input] hasn't changed since the last build AND
2. have GNU Make not run (compile) if [source] didn't change (logically) since the last build.

All I can think currently is to screw with the modified dates of files (not even sure if possible) and set modified of [metadata] to the oldest date of all [source]. Is there a better way?

Comment: Isn't [ccache](https://ccache.samba.org) already purposed to do this?

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about this. I'm a bit torn. On one hand I'd clearly benefit from this in many cases (where I'm doing different builds), on the other hand I don't like to introduce dependencies for my users if it can be done in a few lines of bash / Makefile code.

Answer (score 0):

When writing this question I had an idea for an answer. This isn't *intirely* according to the Makefile spirit of always touching targets, but I think it should work for my usecase:

```
[source_temp] : [source] [metadata]
   < $< (preprocess) > $@

[source] : [source_temp]
   copy $< to $@ if new or changed

[executable] : [source]
   (compile) -c $< -o $@
```

As you can see the second line doesn't always touch $@ but I think I can live with that. The big advantage of this is that it will only execute all the `diff` commands in the second rule every time, which should be considerably faster than `(preprocess)`.

What's your opinion on this solution?